# Java int to fraction

Tags: java, regex

How can i change `4 -1/4 -5` to `4/1 -1/4 -5/1`  using regex?

```
String str = "4 -1/4 -5";
String regex = "(-?\\d+/\\d+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
```

My code finding only fraction but i want to find integer without fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(?<=-| |^)(\d+)(?!\d*\/)`

Explanation:

`(?<=...)` - positive lookahead, assert, what precedes matches pattern inside

`-| |^` - match either `-`, , or beginning of a line `^`

`(\d+)` - match one or more digits and store in first capturing group

`(?!\d*\/)` - negative lookahead, assert what follows is not zero or mroe digits followed by `\/`.

Replace it with `\1/1`, so first capturing group followed by `/1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2k4EdL/2)

Comment: This answer is a bit dangerous. At least you need to use possessive quantifiers. Otherwise, `11/3` will become `1/11/3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = str.replaceAll("(?<!/)\\b\\d+\\b(?!/)", "$0/1");
```

looks for entire numbers (`\b\d+\b`), not preceded by (`(?<!/)`) nor followed by a slash (`(?!/)`), and adds `/1` to them.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do here, but if you want to remove the slashes you can use:

`str.replaceAll("\\/", " ");`

This will leave you with a string having only the integers.

Comment: I don't want to remove the slashes. I want to add slashes under integer. For example i want to chance 5 to 5/1.

Comment: Your question was kind of contradictory, on the last line you say you want to find the
`"integer without fraction"`, one can assume you want just the number itself.

Comment: I guess I didn't quite know what I wanted to tell you. Excuse me.